# Azure-cli commands to configure a Virtual network gateway

Tags: azure, azure-cli, openvpn, azure-vpn

What is the azure-cli command to configure settings for a Point-to-site VPN?

I am looking for the az equivalent in code of doing these steps through the Portal:

```
- From the settings section for a Virtual network gateway
- Click on Point-to-site configuration settings
- Set address pool, tunnel type, authentication type, and a root certificate
- Save
- Download VPN Client (vpnconfig.ovpn file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the virtual network gateway through Azure CLI commands, you can follow the steps in [Create a route-based VPN gateway using CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/create-routebased-vpn-gateway-cli). But when the step comes to create the virtual network gateway, you should add some more parameters.

**--address-prefixes**

Space-separated list of CIDR prefixes representing the address space for the P2S client.

**--client-protocol**

Protocols to use for connecting.

accepted values: IkeV2, OpenVPN, SSTP

So the complete command will like below:

```
az network vnet-gateway create \
  -n VNet1GW \
  -l eastus \
  --public-ip-address VNet1GWIP \
  -g TestRG1 \
  --vnet VNet1 \
  --gateway-type Vpn \
  --sku VpnGw1 \
  --vpn-type RouteBased \
  --address-prefixes 192.168.0.0/24 \
  --client-protocol OpenVPN
```

Then you need to upload the certificate for the root certificate:

```
az network vnet-gateway root-cert create -g TestRG1 -n vpncliCert --gateway-name VNet1GW --public-cert-data path/to/your/certificate
```

When all the things are OK, you can download the VPN client to use. Do not forget to install the client certificate for the root certificate in your machine.

Comment: It took me an hour trying to find "point-to-site" configuration with `az cli` before this answer explained that this is called "address-prefixes" because of course it is. Thank you!!!